# Why doesn't my minecraft work?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, minecraft-legacy-console

Almost every update I do from my minecraft xbox 360, the screen slightly turns dark and when I try to load my world only one joystick works. And yes, I did see if the joystick worked, and it worked perfectly. Its the second minecraft game that I bout and don't want to waste another perfect 20 dollars. Please help

Comment: I mean joystick work

Comment: Can you give us a little bit more information? Are you playing Minecraft when the updates happen? Has this happened with any other games?

Comment: No. Just Minecraft

Comment: The newest update that we recently had for minecraft xbox 360

Comment: It is probably a bug or little space, but I don't know.

Comment: Did the update occur *while* you were playing Minecraft? And If so, Did you restart Minecraft, or just keep playing?

Comment: No, the update did not occur while i was playing.No, how do you restart minecraft on the xbox?